# First Time Traveler US Citizen traveling to Pakistan

Tags: visas, us-citizens, pakistan

I'm American and I have never been out of the United States. Is it true that if I visit Pakistan for the first time I'll only be able to stay a month? I hope this isn't true. I want to stay longer.

Comment: I would definitely suggest reading all of http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/pakistan.html, especially the "Entry, Exit & Visa Requirements" section which starts *"U.S. citizens must have a valid passport and valid Pakistani visa to enter and exit Pakistan for any purpose."*

Answer (score 1):

The limit you mentioned is only for the [business visa on arrival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Pakistan) for US citizens (and along with that many other countries).

The business visa on arrival has quite a bit of regulations behind it.

- You may obtain a visa on arrival when traveling on business for a maximum stay of 30 days if you have a local sponsor who will obtain an approval from the immigration authorities at the port of arrival.
- You must also hold either a recommendation letter from the Chamber of Commerce and Industries (CC&I) in the US or an invitation letter from a business organization recommended by the organization/association in Pakistan or recommendation letter by Investor Consular of Board of Investment posted at Pakistan missions abroad.

If you don't have all these requirements fulfilled you should apply for a tourist visa before visiting the country wherein the duration isn't exactly mentioned on the [Pakistan Embassy website](http://www.embassyofpakistanusa.org/consa6.php), but it would likely depend on your plan when visiting there.

**Either way, if you need more than 30 days, apply for a visa before you travel and you can get it.**